# Regex - Start from Right, End at Equals

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following uri structure:

xxx.com/xxx/xxx?action=&anmp;someId=12334454

Does anyone know how I can use regular expressions to return the numbers at the end of the uri/url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- `&anmp;` in your url is not correct

2- You don't need regex to parse Uris

```
string url = "http://xxxa.com/xxxa/xxxa?action=&someId=12334454";
var id = new Uri(url).ParseQueryString()["someId"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)$
```

Try this. just grab the capture   see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/34

Answer (score 1):

Regex matches left to right, but you can anchor the end of your expression to the end of the string with `$`:

```
=(\d+)$
```

This will look for an `=` sign, then capture 1+ digits, anchored to the end of the string.

---

Or you can use a lookbehind to assert for the `=` without actually matching it to avoid using the capture group:

```
(?<==)\d+$
```